# Confusion regarding conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value

I am having a confusion regarding conditional expectation. 
Let $X\sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,2)$ and $Y$ be a random variable such that $Y=\max\{X,2-X\}$.

So basically $Y=X$ if $X>2-X$ i.e. $X>1$ and $Y=2-X$ if $X<1$. I have to find $E(Y)$, which can be written as $E(Y\mid X>1)×P(X>1)+ E(Y\mid X<1)×P(X<1)$. I write

> $E(Y\mid X>1)=E(X)=1$

Is this correct?
If not, can you suggest me an alternative way to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: No, it is $E[X\mid X>1]$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom so if i have to find $E(Y)$ then how should i proceed?

Comment: That isn't in your question, but $E[Y]=\int \max(x,2-x)f_X(x)\,dx$ directly, which is the same as $E[Y]=E[YI_{X>1}]+E[YI_{X<1}]$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom am i right in writing $E(YI_{X>1})=\int_{1}^2xdx$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By law of total expectation, you are correct that

$$E[Y]=E[Y\mid X>1]P(X>1)+E[Y\mid X<1]P(X<1)\tag{1}$$

Now for the conditional expectations, you have $E[Y\mid X>1]=E[X\mid X>1]$ (you cannot drop the condition $X>1$ because $X$ is not independent of $\{X>1\}$) and similarly for $E[Y\mid X<1]$.

Since $E[Y\mid A]=\frac{E[Y1_A]}{P(A)}$ for any event $A$ with positive probability, $(1)$ is just

$$E[Y]=E[Y1_{X>1}]+E[Y1_{X<1}]$$

Here $1$ is an indicator variable, so you have

\begin{align}
E[Y1_{X>1}]=E[X1_{X>1}]&=\int x1_{x>1}f_X(x)\,dx
\\&=\frac12\int_1^2 x\,dx
\end{align}

But you can forget all of this and simply find the expectation using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) theorem:

$$E[Y]=\int \max(x,2-x)f_X(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!